# Two login sessions under one domain name

Tags: authentication, web, session-cookies

I'm going to develop a website that has a registration / login system. This website will have a sub-folder where I'll dump in a MyBB forum. It will have it's own registration / login system as well.

Will these login sessions interfere with eachother?

Comment: It depends how you set the sessions up.

Comment: Yes that's true and that's what I've been thinking as well, but I just got a 'feeling' that there may be some problems so I'm just making sure.